# Undefined List Item

Tags: javascript, html, css, undefined

I've got a problem.

```js
let liList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
console.log(liList[1].innerText);
```

```css
ul {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.cekirano::before {
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  content: '';
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

li.cekirano {
  background-color: rgb(97, 97, 97);
  color: white;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

span {
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  text-transform: none;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hit the gym<span>×</span></li>
  <li>Pay bills<span>×</span></li>
  <li>Meet George<span>×</span></li>
  <li>Buy eggs<span>×</span></li>
  <li>Read a book<span>×</span></li>
  <li>Organize<span>×</span></li>
</ul>
```

But there's an error when I run it into a internet browser:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerText')
at script.js:2:26

I'm trying to make a to-do list like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_todolist.asp) on my own. I looked how they did it, and I did similar thing with their code and it gives me good result.
Thank you in advance, N.P.

Comment: As it runs without error on stackoverflow, are you sure that your code executes _after_ the DOM has been built? Otherwise `document.getElementsByTagName` returns empty-handed which would be consistent with the reported error message. Remedy: the code in an event handler: `document.addEventHandler('DOMContentLoaded', () => { /* your code goes here */ });`.

Answer (score -1):

move the script to the bottom

**final code would be like this**

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>


    <style>
        ul {
            width: 60%;
            margin: auto;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 0;
        }

        li {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 10px;
            padding-left: 35px;
            position: relative;
        }

        ul li {
            background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
        }

        ul li:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
        }

        ul li:hover {
            background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        li.cekirano::before {
            border-color: #fff;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
            content: '';
            top: 10px;
            left: 16px;
            height: 15px;
            width: 7px;
            position: absolute;
            transform: rotate(45deg);
        }

        li.cekirano {
            background-color: rgb(97, 97, 97);
            color: white;
            text-decoration: line-through;
        }

        span {
            padding: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 5px;
            text-transform: none;
            top: 5px;
            bottom: 5px;
        }
    </style>

    <ul>
        <li>Hit the gym<span>×</span></li>
        <li>Pay bills<span>×</span></li>
        <li>Meet George<span>×</span></li>
        <li>Buy eggs<span>×</span></li>
        <li>Read a book<span>×</span></li>
        <li>Organize<span>×</span></li>
    </ul>
    <script>
        let liList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
        console.log(liList[1].innerText);
    </script>
</body>
```